# one to one relation with middle table

Tags: php, laravel

I have a invoice model which can belong to a product or a plan ... my database looks like this

```
invoices : id , type (enum:product,plan) , price 
invoice_products : invoice_id , product_id 
invoice_plans : invoice_id  , plan_id 
plans : id , title 
products : id , title
```

when I want to show my invoices for the purchased item I have to write something like

```
   $purachse = $invoice->invoice_plan->plan ;
```

Or

```
   $purachse = $invoice->invoice_product->product ;
```

Is there a way to get rid of `invoice_product` in my relation?

I want to get the `product` or `plan` but I don't want to keep going through `invoice_product` I prefer laravel to handle that for me.

something like `belongsToMany` but for 1-1 relation .. there is `hasOneThrough` but it wont work as I thought.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Laravel polymorphic relations: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-polymorphic-relations